# Starting minikube on Windows 7 fails to start with - Error getting state for host: machine does not exist

Tags: windows, windows-7, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

Have been trying to setup Kubernetes for local development on my Windows 7 machine with a VirtualBox VM Driver. Installing and running minikube fails each time with the below error:

```
D:\minikube>minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
Starting local Kubernetes v1.9.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E0219 09:47:24.441727    4220 start.go:159] Error starting host: Error getting state for host: machine does not exist.

 Retrying.
E0219 09:47:24.448727    4220 start.go:165] Error starting host:  Error getting state for host: machine does not exist
E0219 09:47:54.448727    4220 util.go:151] Error uploading error message: : 
Post https://clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/k8s-minikube/events:report?key=AIzaSyACUwzG0dEPcl-eOgpDKnyKoUFgHdfoFuA: dial tcp 172.217.25.138:443: i/o timeout
```

I suspected this may be happening due to minikube cache downloading at a network drive folder (N:) due to enterprise configurations in my laptop, however, copying the `.minikube` folder from `N:\.minikube` to `C:\Users\abc123\.minikube` has not abated the problem.

Do let me know if someone has managed to solve it.

Comment: I have even tried this command below, so that it points to my cache to pick-up the minikube VM:

`C:\Users\abc123>minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox --iso-url="C:/Users/abc123/.minikube/cache/iso/minikube-v0.25.1.iso"`

It has not helped either.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, were you able to get a resolution for it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into the same error on osx after re-installing minikube. Simply deleting the minikube VM and restarting fixed everything:

```
$ minikube delete
$ minikube start
```

Answer (score 1):

- Go to C:\Users\\
- Delete the .minikube folder
- Start minikube (minikube.exe start --kubernetes-version="v1.10.0" --vm-driver="virtualbox")

Answer (score 0):

Try using powershell/cygwin instead of cmd.

Also delete .minikube folder

do minikube delete
then minikube start

Answer (score 0):

In certain scenarios, it may be an issue with your VM driver. If you don't specify one, it may default to VirtualBox. But if you have HyperV instead (due to installing docker on windows, for example) then it won't start. You may have to start it like so:

`minikube start --vm-driver hyperv`

Or whatever is appropriate.